# Здесь правильно написать "речи" или "речах"?

Tags: грамматика

В [этом книжном тексте](http://hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-079.htm) сказано:

> прилагательные, образованные при помощи этой приставки, употребляются и в *книжной* и в *разговорной* **речи**.

Разве не должно здесь быть "и в книжной и в разговорной **речах**"? Мы ведь говорим "в английском и немецком **языках**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, конечно.

"Речь" в это значении (Тот или иной вид, стиль языка... - Кузнецов) вообще не имеет множественного числа, но оно тут и не нужно. Вполне можно сказать и "в книжном и в разговорном языке". "В книжном и в разговорном стиле" - т.е. даже со словами, множественное число имеющими, смысл фразы не предполагает его использование.

Вообще выбор числа в таких случаях определяется целым рядом соображений, не в последнюю очередь тем, насколько автор противопоставляет объекты ("языки", "стили") друг другу.

> > Мы ведь говорим "в английском и немецком языках".

"Мы" вполне может сказать и "в английском и немецком языке". Но тут обе формы одинаково уместны, не знаю даже, чем руководствоваться автору. Только его собственным авторским чутьем.

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае используется ед.число существительного: и в книжной, и в разговорной речи.
Фактически эта запись соответствует следующей: **и в книжной речи, и в разговорной речи.** Эти понятия не существуют совместно, мы их не объединяем, а пользуемся одним из них.

В общем случае употребление существительного во мн. числе также возможно, например: Эти изменения коснутся земельной, административной и военной реформ. Здесь реформы связаны между собой, они составляют единый пакет, где будут введены изменения.  Можно сказать: Эти изменения коснутся следующих реформ: земельной, административной и военной.

Comment: Vera, из вашего текста следует, что множественное число все-таки возможно. Это не так. В этом значении у слова "речь" нет множественного числа.

Comment: Существительное "речь" В ОБЩЕМ СЛУЧАЕ может иметь форму мн. числа, эта форма СУЩЕСТВУЕТ (например: здесь не услышишь умных речей), хотя в сочетаниях "письменная речь"  и "устная речь" используется только ед.ч.  И еще пример про "связанность": встреча советской и американской армий на Эльбе. Мы же не скажем: встреча советской и американской армии на Эльбе. А как это объяснить? В этом случае мы используем мн. число, так как в ОДНОЙ ситуации присутствуют (сосуществуют) ОБЕ армии.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с behemothus. Хочу также напомнить, что в оппозиции "единственное - множественное число" маркированным членом является множественное число.